# Acknowledge and Exception but continue anyway

Tags: c#

Simple script where you import a txt file to sum together all the number values. In the txt file there is one letter (incorrectly entered) instead of a number.

[image: StreamReader]

12.30
14.30
16.30
17.89
y  // Incorrect entry

Using try/catch will ensure that I am aware of this mistake.

[image]

As a *learning exercise* how do I still get the exception comment yet still allow the script to continue. To give an output EVENTHOUGH the final total will be wrong?

[image]

Comment: [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Please copy/paste your code as text (formatted as code), not an image. You can use try/catch to catch your exceptions, but as @quaabaam has pointed out, it's better to use `TryParse` and avoid the exceptions completely

Comment: Where does salesFigure come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is for learning, I would recommend using TryParse rather than Parse and rather than placing code in the form, use a class as shown next where return information is done with tuples and [deconstruct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct) by the caller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class Operations
    {
        public static (decimal total, List<int> linesBad, Exception exception) GetTotals(string fileName)
        {
            List<int> badLines = new();
            decimal total = 0;

            try
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new(fileName))
                {
                    int index = 0;
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        if (decimal.TryParse(reader.ReadLine(), out var result))
                        {
                            total += result;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            badLines.Add(index);
                        }

                        index++;
                    }
                }

                return (total, badLines, null);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (total, badLines, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To keep things simple I use a Console app. Using return values use `total` for your label, `badLines` if not empty has any line that was not a decimal and `exception` if there was a runtime exception e.g. missing file.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var (total, badLines, exception) = Operations.GetTotals("example.txt");

    if (exception is null)
    {

        Console.WriteLine($"Total: {total:C2}");

        if (badLines.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Bad lines: {string.Join(",", badLines)}");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to capture the exception message in general (ignoring TryParse etc)

```
  string message = null;
  try
  {
       // do stuf that might throw
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      message = e.Message;
  }
  if (message != null)
  {
      // error happened and we have the message
  }
  else
  {
       // all ok
  }
```